# Understanding and using Parse many to many relations

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfrelation

I have 2 tables in Parse like so:

```
Users:
(PFUsers table with all Parse data)
belongsToGroups (A Parse Relation to Groups which is many to many)

Groups:
groupId
name
groupMembers (A Parse Relation to Users which is also many to many)
```

I have the following code:

```
PFObject *groups = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Groups"];
groups[@"name"] = name;
syncUsers[@"isActive"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
//[groups saveInBackground];

PFUser *current = [PFUser currentUser];
PFRelation *relation = [syncUsers relationforKey:@"groupMembers"];
[relation addObject:current];
[groups saveEventually];

PFRelation *relation2 = [current relationforKey:@"belongsToGroups"];
[relation2 addObject:groups];
[current saveEventually];
```

First, the top 2 blocks of code work fine, but how do I update the relationship in Users so that I can do View Relation in Parse and see my groups?

Two, do I need to create the Relation in users AND groups so that it can be many to many?

Comment: If you want to query both ways, you need to add an inverse relationship in Group. It seems "Groups" is actually a "Group", so you should use singular version of the word; not plural. Also, since isActive sounds like a bool, you should use [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] instead of numberWithInt. Is the last block not creating a relation in your User class?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide#manytomany

Comment: The last block does not create a relationship. I wish it did but why doesn't it?

Comment: Have you created a "Relation" on the User class in the data browser?

Comment: Yes. I guess something is up with the PFUser class maybe? As its not a regular PFObject?

Comment: PFUser is a PFObject. Just a special one. Try [current save]; instead and let me know if there is a difference.

Comment: Yeah I'll check it out when I get home tonight and make sure my dashboard browser is set up correctly too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereKey:equalTo:` on a relation `column` and pass it a `PFObject`. This query will then return all Teacher objects which have this student in their "students" relation:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Teacher"];
[query whereKey:@"students" equalTo:student];
```

In this example, the student is a `PFObject` with a `className` that matches the relation in "students". If this is a `relation` of `PFUsers` and you're looking for the current user's "Teacher"s, you'd use:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Teacher"];
[query whereKey:@"students" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

Comment: So what's the code to get all Teachers of a Student AND all students of a Teacher then? I see the first but where's the second

Answer (score 1):

First for a relation you need that both objects exist in the Parse Database. Then you must use the PFRelation object and save the object with the relation.

I recommend using CodeCloud for stablishing relationships so you can share the code with Android or Web Apps.

```
// Objects
PFObject *student = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Student" objectId:@"xauj37H"];

PFObject *teacher = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Teacher" objectId:@"xJdcj238"];

// Add a student to the teacher object

// Get the students relation
PFRelation *studentsForTeacher = [teacher relationForKey:@"students"];

// Add a student
[studentsForTeacher addObject:student];

// save the teacher, use InBackground instead 
[teacher save];

// Now add a teacher for the student
PFRelation *teachersForStudent = [student relationForKey:@"teachers"];

[teachersForStudent addObject:teacher];

// Save the student
[student save];

// And now you can query the students of a teacher or the teachers of a student

// Students for a Teacher
PFQuery *studentsQuery = [studentsForTeacher query];

[studentsQuery find];

// Teachers for a Student
PFQuery *teachersQuery = [teachersForStudent query];

[teachersQuery find];
```

Comment: So my idea above is correct. must be something weird with saving for PFUser class

Comment: if your are editing PFUser you should use Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() in CodeCloud in order to bypass ACL